# Matplotlib bug, displays values in charts that does not exist in the given array

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-lab

I am facing a weird bug.

Here is the code for plotting the chart:

```
import matplotib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
ax.hist(DF.A.values, alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,80+1,step=2),rotation=50)
plt.show()
```

It displays the following chart 
 [image: chart with bug]

The problem is there is not value between 0 and 8.0. Actually there is a gap between 0 and 14.0:

```
in : set(DF.A.values.tolist())
out : {0.0, 14.0, 15.0, 15.5, 16.0, 16.5, ... , 84.0}
```

I wonder why it displays non existent values. Besides, I shotdown the kernel, restarted it, and run the cells, it gives the same weird result.

Notes: 
This is done on jupyter lab notebook.
Jupyter lab version : 0.35.3 
Python version: Python 3.7.4 (Anaconda, Inc. on linux) 
Matplotlib version: 3.0.2

Comment: presumably the first bin goes from 0 to 8.  the values returned from `hist` would tell you.  the second parameter `bins` lets you specify the binning, either a count or the actual edges

Comment: Well, `0.0` ***is*** in your data, and it apparently appears quite often. So you have 600000 zeros in your data, and hence the bar goes up to 600000.

Comment: @SamMason you are right thank you. To enter the parameter `bins` in `hist` as `bins=np.arange(min(DF.A.values ),max(DF.A.values),step=1)` does work, and gives accurate display.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I did not complaint at all that there was 0.0, but values like 2.0, 8.0 and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from my comment: the first (automatically determined) bin went from 0 to 8, so this isn't really a bug

you have a few of options:

1. tell matplotlib that you want more bins, e.g: `ax.hist(DF.A, 50)`
2. pass the bins explicitly, e.g: `ax.hist(DF.A, range(DF.A.max()))`
3. use something else

given this data is apparently a discrete set of values, using `hist` tends to result in a number of binning artifacts, e.g. if two nearby values fall into a bin counts double, while the bins either side will be relatively empty.  an option would be to display the counts of the unique values as this tends to result in less binning artifacts.  for example, this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

a = stats.poisson.rvs(5, size=10000)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)

ax1.hist(a)

a_val, a_num = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
ax2.vlines(a_val, 0, a_num, lw=2, color='C0')
ax2.set_ylim(0, max(a_num)*1.06)
```

gives:

[image: hist vs vlines]

this also highlights the discrete nature of the distribution, with mass only at specific values rather than some continuous support being aggregated into specific bins